# Configurable product are not showing on front end in Multi Store

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, multistore, ce-1.9.1.0

I have problem with my magento 1.9.1.0.  I have one website, 2 store and 2 store view. In my case i am sharing the cart for both store.

My Problem is my configurable product and not showing on front end for both stores. Simple product is showing well. But configurable product is not showing on both stores, i also give correct category and stock as well.

My Store URL is: [**www.image.pk**](http://www.image.pk)

I am using subdomain concept for multiple stores.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are aware of the fact that having 2 stores create two different lists of categories and you have created 2 store views for each store.

First check if they are applied to the correct category, it is fully re-indexed and you have cleaned the cache.

If you can provide more info so we can troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Yes i have applied the product to correct category.  I am using the following step to create the configurable product. 1. First create the configurable product and under it product details, click on the associated product and create quick simple products.  I don't know why my configurable products and not showing. i also check stock option, product visibility to catalog and search, enable option. Category linking to the right product.

Comment: Ok, first, stock option must be allowed on simple products (associated ones), visibility of configurable products set to catalogue and search and simple visibility not set. I can see you use quite a few plugins, perhaps the configuration of one doesn't allow visibility of configurable products.

Comment: ok please let me know how can i fix this problem.

Comment: Did you try the method above? - also would you have external caching? that might be the cause and clear cache folder via ftp/sftp.